# Is there any better way to Get PDF view or Conversion in ASP.NET MVC3 razor CSHTML file

Tags: asp.net, html, css, asp.net-mvc-3

I already use ItextSharp dll for html to pdf but it does not give me styling of external css files used in the page.

Please help and suggest a better solution.

Good day!

Comment: A colleague of mine wrote this post on how to acheive that - check out his blog post and example code here: http://andyck1.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/html-to-pdf-conversion-in-mvc-4.html

Comment: this needs to have a software install on the server, which is highly not allowed by the client and i tried to run locally, it gives MemoryStream error.

Comment: yes sadly this solution does require direct access to the server which you probably wont get in shared hosting environments.

Answer (score 0):

see this open source project i used once: https://github.com/gmanny/Pechkin
It utilizes `wkhtmltopdf` and provides a `dll` without the need to install anything.

Comment: I started off using Pechkin before dropping back to the raw exe. I  have been quite active in the issues section of the Pechkin repo on github - it works like a charm in desktop environments but can be temperamental when running in a hosted environment under IIS - even when using the SynchronizedPechkin version. So you're quite right but Id err on the side of caution until the 100% CPU issues are fixed for web environments.

Comment: hmm. i am still looking some other way.. Fingers crossed!